# nginx reverse-proxy a single URL to a custom server single URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have designed a page on a static page provider, and I'd like to make it available when browsing a domain I own www.example.org (which hits a nginx server)

Target : `https://www.example.org/a/b` --> `https://static-page-provider.com/c`

- The user types `https://www.example.org/a/b` in the URL
- The nginx proxy I own hosted at `https://www.example.org` receives the request on the exact path /a/b  and must proxy-pass :

  - The remote server should receive a GET request at `https://static-page-provider.com/c` with HOST header `static-page-provider.com`
- The user should see `https://www.example.org/a/b` in the URL
- It should work the same for the final address with a slash `https://www.example.org/a/b/` --> `https://static-page-provider.com/c/` (I don't actually care if it's `/c/` or just `/c` for any of the 2 cases

Should be preserved

- https://www.example.org/a/b2 --> https://www.example.org/a/b2
- https://www.example.org/a/b/c --> https://www.example.org/a/b/c
- https://www.example.org/a --> https://www.example.org/a

Is it possible ? (or are there security implications that make this impossible ?). I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway and I see a SSL related error in my log

```
2020/01/23 08:59:43 [error] 30072#0: *499 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.31.28.3, server: www.example.org, request: "GET /a/b/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:443/c/", host: "www.example.com"
```

when trying the config below. I'm also not sure this config does an exact match or not (is `/a/b/c` targeted by the rule ?).

```
location /a/b/ {
    proxy_pass https://static-page-provider.com/c/;
    proxy_set_header host mydomain.static-page-provider.com;
  }
```

Is it possible, if the actual URL containing the final content `https://static-page-provider.com/c/` returns a 301 redirect (for example to `https://static-page-provider-2.com/c/`), to follow the redirection for the user, and the user still sees `https://www.example.org/a/b` ?

Using nginx/1.12.2

EDIT : it kinda works when using a proxy_pass on the static provider without httpS, but then I need to have a secure connection.

Comment: Your example uses `/a/b/` but your question uses `/a/b` - these are different URIs. Also, is there anything in the Nginx error?

Comment: for example; i usr webmail.dom.tld which referers to a other host the user has still only webmail.dom.tld in his browser - so far yes, but i suggest to cache that

Comment: If you consider `/a/b` and `/a/b/` to be different URLs, then I would need to catch both using the location block (I will add this as an example)

There is nothing else in the nginx error apart from the nginx version, but I will add what I see in my error log.

Comment: Can you add you **nginx** SSL configuration (`ssl_ciphers` and so on). Maybe **nginx** and the provider do not have any encryption algorithm in common. At the same time, I don't think your web hosting will mind if you add its real domain.